# Hierarchical query in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have hierarchical data as follows.

```
|Serial No | Primary Flag |Prev SerialNo|
| 101       | 1            |   56        |
 | 56       | 0            |    NULL     |
 | 505      | 0            |    NULL     |
 | 223      |  1           |    156      |
 | 156      | 0            |     93      |
 | 93       | 0            |     42      |
42           | 0            | NULL  |
```

First two rows are related by Previous serial number when primary flag, so total counts in their hierarchy is 2

Third row is not related to any thing since Previous serial number is NULL., so total count is 0.

Fourth row is related to below 3 records, so total count is 4.

I need a query to find the total related counts for rows when Primary flag is 1.How can I achieve this in Teradata?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to return a row for Serial_No 505, you can use a recursive query and aggregation:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
  SELECT h.Serial_No AS Primary_SerialNo, h.Serial_No, h.Prev_SerialNo, 1 (INTEGER) as Level
   FROM hierTbl h WHERE h.Primary_Flag=1
 UNION ALL
  SELECT r.Primary_SerialNo, h.Serial_No, h.Prev_SerialNo, r.Level+1
    FROM hierTbl h JOIN r ON r.Prev_SerialNo = h.Serial_No
)
Select Primary_SerialNo, MAX(Level) as Related
FROM r GROUP BY 1;
```